# How to insert empty row before columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as so:

```
A   B   C   D
x   x   x   x
x   x   x   x
x   x   x   x
```

where A B C D are the column names. I want to insert an empty row above the columns so it will look like:

```
Nan Nan Nan Nan
A   B   C   D
x   x   x   x
x   x   x   x
x   x   x   x
```

I've tried something like

```
df.loc[len(df)] = 0
df = df.shift()
df.loc[0] = None
```

which gives me:

```
A   B   C   D
Nan Nan Nan Nan
x   x   x   x
x   x   x   x
x   x   x   x
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: "I want to insert an empty row above the columns" you do realise this is extremely pointless and is counterproductive?

Comment: Your question can be answered by `df.columns = [[np.nan]*df.shape[1], [*df]]` but the output will not look as you expect. I sense an XY problem, can you tell us why you'd want to do this?

Comment: You can't have a row above the column name... it's illogical! What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have some other code that I cannot modify that expects to receive a data frame in this format. I will try your suggestion thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use a multilevel index:

```
df.columns= pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(None, col) for col in df.columns])
```